# Play Framework 2.2.1 Production mode: "Asset not found"

Tags: playframework

I saw that there are similar questions already, but non of them was really helpful for my case. So just briefly, I have an application created with Play Framework 2.2.1. I have the files on my Linux server, I set up Apache as described in Play Documentation. But once I start the app in production mode I get the massage:

**"Asset not found: GET /home/rmurtagh/UKClinicalAuditSearch"**

This is the directory where the app is. I have tried out everything I could find on the Internet, but without any success. I just don't have a clue what the issue can be.

Hope that someone can help.

Phil

Comment: What is Your apache config ? Could You paste somewhere fragment that refers to play app ?

Comment: Hey, meanwhile I managed to figure out the problem. I had to flush the JVM cache and restart Apache. This combo worked for me. But thank you for you readiness to help.